# Custom icons in KML not showing up on google maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

So I have a large KML with many custom icons that I want to have show up on a google map (API v3). You can see the example page here: http://mexicometro.org/metro/line1/pantitlan/

the kml I am loading is here: http://mexicometro.org/doc.kml

I can't figure out why the custom icons are not showing up. I believe that my kml is well-written (I did it all by hand); some nesting issues were pointed out to me in the past, but I believe that I have fixed all those.

So can anyone help me pin down the problem? Is it something wrong with my kml? it used to work in the api v2.

Thanks!

Comment: Getting a 404 error on the KML file. Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your Style elements in the style definitions at the top and not in the Placemarks. Style element in the Placemark does not seem to be supported according to the documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#placemark

Comment: Oh no..  I think you're right, but I have over 300 unique icons. I think I may need to place them all in new style definitions..  No!!! Too much work!!!

Comment: Actually, I tried it with a simple kml, 1 marker, 1 polyline, no style info in the placemark (icon referenced in the styleUrl), and it didn't work. I'm going to try going another tack, using the maps API for directly putting my markers.

Comment: Ok, I havent worked with polyline but I never had any problems with custom marker icons.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, then I realized that it was a caching issue.  Even if you tell your browser to not cache anything Google still will.  Make sure to change the name of the kml file to ensure no possible caching.